# Why are my debug options or breakpoint disabled?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

"Step into" , "Step Out" and "Step over" buttons turned disabled , how can I get it back? I'm using visual studio 2019 community edition latest version. My solution config is already set to Debug.

Comment: Your debug session is currently not stopped in a breakpoint ...

Comment: @derpirscher yes, but I need to do "step into" , even if I delete all the breakpoints it's still on disable

Comment: You can only use those options when your debug session is stopped either on a breakpoint, uncaught exception or already stepping in to/through/over the code.

Comment: I only restated what @derpirscher said.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not get it at first